# defaultValue on sharedPreference key is always 0

Tags: android

The defaultValue is always being returned as 0, despite my attempt to return a different value when the pref key does not exist. I wonder why. Here's my piece of code -

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
public static final String PREFS_OLD_TRIM = "trimName";
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
int trim_val = settings.getInt(PREFS_OLD_TRIM, 7);
```

I know for sure, in the initial run, that there is no pref key - PREFS_OLD_TRIM. So, i was expecting trim_val to get a value of 7. But it's getting 0.

Am i missing anything? Thanks. I am targeting API Level 8 device set.

Comment: are you sure,you are getting proper SharedPreferences in settings variable?i mean,it returns a SharedPreferences object to settings?

Comment: have you tried calling the `getSharedPreferences` method inside your `onCreate` method?

Comment: it's currently getting called in onCreate method.

Comment: yes. because other values are as i expect them to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be on the safe side try changing PREFS_OLD_TRIM to random value at every run - this will make you sure that there is no such key in your preference file.

Comment: jeez. thx for the idea. it worked. i completed erased all the preferences and it worked with the same PREFS_OLD_TRIM key this time.

Answer (score 0):

One thing for sure is, Preference will always return only the default value until you provide some value to it and commit(save). So here in this case you are trying to retrieve a value which is not present in the shared preference which obviously will return only the default value despite whatever value you might ask it to return.

Comment: Well, that goes against it's documention: Returns
Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue. Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not an int.